# LCM of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, least-common-multiple

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$There is a nice property of Fibonacci numbers which says that:

$$\gcd(F_{a_1}, \ldots, F_{a_n}) = F_{\gcd(a_1, \ldots, a_n)}$$

I am curious is there anything similar with respect to $\lcm$?

Clearly $\lcm(F_{a_1}, \ldots, F_{a_n}) = F_{\lcm(a_1,\ldots, a_n)}$ is not true, but is there anything better then to use $\lcm(a, b) = \frac{ab}{\gcd(a, b)}$ and to use associative law of $\lcm$?

Comment: Traces of [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fibonacci-lcm/problem) are visible here ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is already studied [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL10/Farrokhi/farrokhi20.pdf) (see Corollary 3.4). It is shown that the least common multiple of two Fibonacci numbers is a Fibonacci number if and only if one of them divides the other.